# Evaluate the norm of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Can someone help me on this question. I want to compute the norm of the following operator

$$l:\mathbb R^N\longrightarrow \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R); (x_1,\cdots,x_N)\mapsto (x_i - x_j)_{1\leq i,j\leq N}.$$
The norm on $\mathbb R^N$ is the Euclidean norm and on $\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ is 
$$|A|=\sum_{i,j} |a_{i,j}|.$$

If not possible how can I get estimates on this norm?